# Applying Gram-Schmidt Process to transform set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

I have a question that goes as follows:

[image]

And below is my written solution to the question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF05T.jpg

I just wanted to know if I've approached this question correctly and whether or not my solution is actually correct.

Comment: You can check for yourself by computing the integrals on the new basis.

Comment: You mean if I substitute the new basis into the integral, I should get 1?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the first element. Then remove the projection of the second vector along the first vector, and normalize that result:
$$
     e_1 = \frac{1}{\|u_1\|}u_1 \\
     e_2 = \frac{u_2-\langle u_2,e_1\rangle e_1}{\|u_2-\langle u_2,e_1\rangle e_1\|}
$$
This is the standard Gram-Schmidt process.

Answer (score 0):

We have $<1,1>=2,<1,x>=0,<x,x>=\dfrac23$.

From this,

$$<1+x,1+x>=2+2\cdot0+\frac23=\frac83$$

$$<1+3x,1+3x>=2+6\cdot0+9\frac23=8$$

$$<1+x,1+3x>=2+4\cdot0+3\frac23=4$$

and your solution is not right.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what your working process was behind the first line where $<1, 1>$ = 2, etc.

Comment: @Broadsword93: just using the definition of $<p,q>$.

Comment: Yes, but where did the $<1, 1>$, $<1, x>$, etc. values come from?

Comment: @Broadsword93: just using the definition of $<p,q>$.

Comment: There must be some gap in my knowledge because I've followed the process as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmU5LhVbO08&ab_channel=MathsStatsUNSW where that lecturer had the following: $<$1, $t$, $t^2$$ >$, I had $< $1 + $x$$, $1 + $3x$$  >$

Comment: @Broadsword93: I am not solving the question, I am checking your result, as requested !!

Comment: That's fine and appreciate your help. It's just that I don't understand or don't follow why what I did was wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113707/discussion-between-broadsword93-and-yves-daoust).